# Where is the Jacobian?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

From Berkeley problems in Mathematics, 5.5.4.

> > Compute the area of the image of the unit disc $D = \{z \mid |z| < 1\}$ under the map $f(z) = z + \frac{z^2}{2}$.

The solution is given.

> > $f$ is injective since $$f(z) = f(w) \Rightarrow (z-w)(1 + \frac{z+w}{2}) = 0,$$ and $z+w = -2$ is impossible for $z,w$ in the unit disc. Then, with $z = x+iy$,

$$\mathrm{Area} = \int_D |f'(z)|^2 \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = \int_D 1 + 2x + x^2 + y^2 \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$$ $$= \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} 1 + 2r\cos \theta + r^2 \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}r = \frac{3\pi}{2}.$$

The last step confuses me. Why don't we need to multiply the integrand by $r$ when we convert to polar coordinates? The solution just substitutes $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and $x = r \cos \theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a typo. You should multiply by $r$ as you say, and the given answer corresponds with what you get when you do so. (But not with the formula you have written.)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_D|f'(z)|^2 \; r \, d\theta \, dr &= \int_D|1+re^{i\theta}|^2 \; r \, d\theta \, dr\\
&=\int_D \left[1+r\left(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}\right)+r^2 \right]\; r \, d\theta \, dr\\
&=\int_D \left(1+r^2 \right)\; r \, d\theta \, dr\\
&=2\pi \int_0^1 r+r^3\,dr\\
&=2\pi \left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\right]=\frac{3\pi}{2}
\end{align*}
$$